# Is it possible to get the binary name of a class from the raw bytes of the class alone?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class file such as `Foo.class` or `Foo$Bar.class`, compiled from the following java source file:

```
package com.foo.bar;
public class Foo {
  class Bar {
  }
}
```

**Is it possible to analyze the bytes in the class and determine that the binary name of the class should be `com.foo.bar.Foo`?**

I'm sending classes over a network and I am trying to determine whether the bytes are sufficient or I also need to somehow pre-determine and send the binary names as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary name is stored in the class file. From [§4.1 The `ClassFile` Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1) of the *Java Virtual Machine Specification* (JVMS), you can see the following item:

> `this_class`
>
> The value of the `this_class` item must be a valid index into the `constant_pool` table. The `constant_pool` entry at that index must be a `CONSTANT_Class_info` structure (§4.4.1) representing the class or interface defined by this `class` file.

And from [§4.4.1 The `CONSTANT_Class_info` Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.1) of the JVMS:

> The `CONSTANT_Class_info` structure is used to represent a class or an interface:
>
> ```
> CONSTANT_Class_info {
>     u1 tag;
>     u2 name_index;
> }
> ```
>
> The items of the `CONSTANT_Class_info` structure are as follows:
>
> `tag`
>
> The tag item has the value `CONSTANT_Class` (7).
>
> `name_index`
>
> The value of the `name_index` item must be a valid index into the `constant_pool` table. The `constant_pool` entry at that index must be a `CONSTANT_Utf8_info` structure (§4.4.7) representing a valid binary class or interface name encoded in internal form (§4.2.1).
>
> *[...]*

So, you do not need to separately send the name of the class alongside the class file.

If this is related to class loading, note a `ClassLoader` accepts a binary name and then tries to load the corresponding class, not the other way around. And unless you're working with reflection the name is automatically given to the class loader; you don't need to know it ahead of time. Otherwise, if you are just trying to get the binary name from the class file, then you can study the specification linked above to manually parse the class file. But it would probably be much easier to use an existing library, such as *ASM*, *Javassist*, *Byte Buddy*, and so on. With [JEP 457: Class-File API (Preview)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/457), there might eventually be a standard API provided by Java itself.